# How to calculate limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm puzzled with this limit. The answer is -0.5, but how to get it? $\lim_\limits{x \to \infty}1-x+\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}$

Comment: What is the limit, I mean $x \to ?$

Comment: @MrYouMath, sorry, my typo

Comment: @Xoque55, I tried to reduce to a common denominator and multiply by conjugate, but it didn't help

Comment: Conjugate multiplication sounds like a good idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to multiply by conjugate not only part with a variable, but all the expression, and this way I calculate it without replace and L'Hospital's Rule.

$\lim_\limits{x \to \infty} 1-x+\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}=\lim_\limits{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{x^3}{x+3}-(x-1)^2}{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}+x-1} = \lim_\limits{x \to \infty}\frac{-x^2+5x-3}{(x+3)\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^3}+\sqrt{x+3}(x-1)}{\sqrt{x+3}}\right)}=\lim_\limits{x \to \infty}\frac{-x^2+5x-3}{\sqrt{x^4+3x^3}+(x+3)(x+1)}$

Now we can see easily that factor before $x^2$ is $-1$ in numerator and $2$ in denominator, so the result is $-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

A start: The interesting part is $\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}-x$. Consider
$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}-x\right)  \left(\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}+x\right) }{ \sqrt{\frac{x^3}{x+3}}+x }.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a totally different approach: Set $\sqrt{\frac{x}{x+3}}=t$ and solve for $x$ to find $x=\frac{3t^2}{1-t^2}$. Put this back into your limit to find $1-\frac{3t^2}{1-t^2} + \frac{3t^3}{1-t^2}$ where $t$ goes to $1$. This is indeterminate and so put everything into one fraction: $\frac{1-4t^2+3t^3}{1-t^2}$ which for $t→1$ now becomes "zero over zero". Apply L'Hospital's Rule to find $-0.5$